# changing custom fiscal years

Tags: setup

I have a client who has custom fiscal years enabled (I didn't do this, don't yell at me).  It's already set up going several years into the future, with a July 1 start date for each year.  Recently they decided to switch their start date to Aug 1 starting this coming year.  So FY 2012-13 is going to end up being 13 months long (July 1 2012 - July 31 2013).

Is there any way to model this in SF?  They'd prefer not to retroactively change past years to start Aug 1.

When I attempt to change the start date of any of their custom fiscal years, I get an error "One or more adjacent years is a Gregorian year and therefore may not be automatically adjusted.  Please fix blocking errors and retry."

Thanks much!

Comment: Unfortunately ,i think a fiscal year cant be extended to 13 months i feel.Even in customizable forecasting we can define our own calendar but it will be adjusted to a year in total !Worth just rechecking customizable forecasting in some developer instance(Not in production for sure )

Comment: I should call support